# Retrieving the results of a table join

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

In a Spring-Boot project there are two entities (consumed from Kafka and) persisted into a PostgreSQL database independently.

Semantically they share the same `id`, and I'd like to join the tables on that and retrieve the results.

Of course, I could go with native queries, etc., but if feasible, I'd prefer a more high-level approach. Maybe retrieving the join results in a new type of data class, if this makes sense?

Here is a minimal example, of what I mean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
data class Foo(
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    val fooval: Long
)

@Repository
interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Long>


@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
data class Bar(
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    val barval: Long
)

@Repository
interface BarRepository : JpaRepository<Bar, Long>
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(
    id        BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    fooval    BIGINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bar(
    id        BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    barval    BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

`Foo` does not own `Bar` or vice versa. The cleanup of those tables (entity deletion) is not an issue.

So my current solution to retrieve the join-result looks like this:

```
@Entity
data class FooBar(
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    val fooval: Long,
    val barval: Long
)

@Repository
interface FooBarRepository : JpaRepository<FooBar, Long> {
    @Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT foo.id, fooval, barval FROM foo, bar WHERE foo.id = bar.id;"
    )
    fun fetchAll(): Iterable<FooBar>
}
```

But is this really the sane way to go?

Comment: Hi Tobias, but this case, you are saying that FooBar it is an entity in the DB and it is NOT true, for hibernate it would look for the table foo_bar in this case as well, right? I would create the class FooBar without been an entity and having a find in a repository from Foo or Bar to findAllFooBar() and call the constructor of the class FooBar from inside the query: "SELECT new your.package.FooBar(foo.id, fooval, barval) from foo, bar WHERE foo.id = bar.id"

Comment: @Brother "for hibernate it would look for the table foo_bar in this case as well, right" As long as only `fetchAll` is called on the `FooBarRepository`, but no other methods, it works. However, you, of course, are totally right, that this is not ideal. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I tried like [this](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/3d982aee6e3c7b13c00053b9bb0e8691#file-application-kt-L38), but it results in `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Iterable entityrelationtest.FooRepository.findAllFooBar()`. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: remove the @entity from FooBar and then in the query you have the table Foo but in the where it is foo.id .. (case sensitive)

Comment: @Brother Thanks. Current code: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/8a191c4bc5a395ba3e79d9ac8c4ecbef

`SELECT new entityrelationtest.FooBar(foo.id, fooval, barval) FROM foo, bar WHERE foo.id = bar.id` results in `QuerySyntaxException: foo is not mapped [SELECT new entityrelationtest.FooBar(foo.id, fooval, barval) FROM foo, bar WHERE foo.id = bar.id]`.

And `SELECT new entityrelationtest.FooBar(Foo.id, fooval, barval) FROM Foo, Bar WHERE Foo.id = Bar.id` results in `IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query ...`

Any idea what's still wrong?

Comment: hI @Tobias Hermann, I added an answer with the code running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation for your scenario working and tested locally:

```
package entityrelationtest

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
data class Foo(
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    val fooval: Long
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
data class Bar(
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    val barval: Long
)

data class FooBar(
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    val fooval: Long,
    val barval: Long
)

@Repository
interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT new entityrelationtest.FooBar(f.id, f.fooval, b.barval) FROM Foo f, Bar b WHERE f.id = b.id")
    fun findAllFooBar(): Iterable<FooBar>
}

@Repository
interface BarRepository : JpaRepository<Bar, Long>

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

It was also missing alias for the tables. And SELECT new to JPA create an object for each line.